# IE8 mailto: does not work - help

Tags: html, internet-explorer, email

Having trouble getting the mailto: to work in IE8 (works fine in chrome)

```
<form action="mailto:admin@example.com&subject=testEmail" enctype="text/plain" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
 <td><img id="content" alt="" height="238" src="images/notion_form_content.png" width="540" /></td>
 <td>

  <input class="editor-input" name="License" type="text" value="TeamPulse License"/><br/>
  <input class="editor-input" name="Name" type="text" value="Name" /><br/>
  <input class="editor-input" name="Email" type="text" value="Email" /><br/>
  <input class="editor-input" name="Company" type="text" value="Company"/><br/>
  <input class="button" type="submit" value=""/>  
 </td>
</tr>

</table>

</form >
```

method="post" creates the body with the input names, so the body looks like this

License=MyLicense
Name=Joe
Email=email@email.com
Company=ACME

This works great in Chrome, but no in IE8 - (Outlook or email client does not launch)

If I do method="get", the email client is launched in IE8 (and chrome) but the body is empty

Comment: This is exactly why you shouldn't post form data with this method. It's unpredictable, and users will get warnings that will likely deter them from submitting data. If at all possible, I recommend setting up a web server that will receive your POST data and send an email itself. It will avoid the numerous problems associated with your current method.

Comment: yes i realize this - this is a very very short temporary solution - id rather not do it this way, but it looks like i have to :( just get something up

Comment: I didn't try this myself, but a quick google search for "IE8 mailto" shows that a lot of people have this problem, and only with IE8. Looks like someone found a solution that worked for them, but it is was a problem with their installation, not with the code: http://www.developerbarn.com/microsoft-windows/1680-ie8-mailto.html#post15329

Comment: @Ben Lee - i've set IE8 to default - and outlook now launches great, its just that for some reason i'm not able to submit the input values into the body.  I can explicity set it in the formAction "&body=blahBlahBlah" but i need user submitted values :(

Comment: unfortunately, I don't know what the problem is then.

Answer (score 1):

Your action is wrong. Use a `?` to start the mailto params, not a `&`. So replace it with this:

```
mailto:admin@example.com?subject=testEmail
```

Comment: well this doesnt really do anything in IE - but i changed it anwyays - the only way i can get IE8 to launch the email client is if i change the method="get" from "post" but the body is empty :(

Comment: @Jerrold, Then what if you go ahead and try changing it to a "get" and getting the request string ready by changing the action to: `mailto:admin@example.com?subject=testEmail&body=`

Comment: getting closer with "post" ("get" doesnt work in chrome)- subject is filled in, default email client is loaded thru IE8, but body is still empty on submit...

Answer (score 0):

Switch the & to a ?

```
mailto:admin@example.co?subject=testEmail&body=This is the body text
```

The & means you are adding extra arguments

Comment: i cant do &body and explicity put the body of the email - i need the user to type in the input fields and have that in the body - if i do "post" it works fine in chrome, but not in IE - email client does not launch

Comment: Honestly, this isn't a great way to compose an email. See here: http://apptools.com/rants/mailto.php Can you use JavaScript here instead? What are you trying to do exactly? Usually you send mail through the web server, not rely on the client side this way.